# Chrome keeps re-validating Javascript files on site, though it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching

I'm a developer of a landing page authoring system.
To make our pages load faster we use a force-cache technique - all the resources (images/js/css/fonts) in a landing page are set to expire in a year. The file paths are unique and the files never change.


It should work find, but there is a problem when browsing those pages in Chrome - when it loads Javascript files that were already cached (*) the browser sometimes connects to the server with an IF-MODIFIED-SINCE header (getting a 304 reply) and sometimes it doesn't. I don't want the browser to connect to the server at all for the Javascript files that were already cached, it slows down the page loading.

(*) already cached: just enter the page more then once, not using F5 (which obviously causes reloading) but by pressing Enter in the address bar, or opening a new tab and entering the same address.

An example page can viewed here: http://mati.ravpage.co.il/placeholders
I analyzed the issue by entering Chrome's dev tools (F12), inspecting the network tab, sorting by Status. Sometimes only the "placeholders" entry get a 304, sometimes also the Javascript entries.

For the Javascript file bugs_mati_...1391870865.js, the HTTP headers are:
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
   Cache-Control:max-age=31536000, public
   Connection:keep-alive
   Content-Encoding:gzip
   Content-Type:application/javascript
   Date:Sat, 08 Feb 2014 14:57:08 GMT
   Expires:Sun, 08 Feb 2015 14:55:25 GMT
   Last-Modified:Sat, 08 Feb 2014 14:47:48 GMT
   Server:NetDNA-cache/2.2
   Transfer-Encoding:chunked
   Vary:Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
   X-Cache:HIT

I don't understand why Chrome behaves the way it does. I can't even reproduce the issue with high confidence, the behavior is erratic. I am lost.
I would appreciate any help,
Thank you in advanced,
Mati

Comment: The only thing that seems *possibly* suspicious is that you're sending a "Last-Modified" header. That seems redundant, since you're also sending "max-age" and an explicit "Expires".

Comment: I removed the "Last-Modified" header but it did not work. [already added it back, the less changes the better]

Comment: last-modified header is not redundant. it can be redundant if u use also etag. they have the same target but etag is more modern